# No option to choose Regional VNET or Affinity for new DocumentDB

Tags: azure, affinity, azure-cosmosdb

I tried to setup Affinity or Regional VNET in Azure preview portal for new DocumentDB.
I can setup this from normal portal, however I am interested in placing DocumentDB and Virtual Machine close to each other so the latency is minimal.

I tried to do it without above. I placed VM and DB in the same region - West US. However latency is huge, about 45 msec. Is it a feature of this new DocumentDB or I just doing something completely wrong?

Thank you
John

Comment: This question will likely be moved to ServerFault or closed, as it's not a programming question (at least not as written). You haven't provided any details on your code that's accessing DocumentDB, so it's really not possible to answer any specifics around that. Also: Remember that the service is currently in Preview.

Comment: How are you measuring latency? On my tests, docdb is and to give me results on an index range query (with the connection hosting about 2000 documents) in about 180ms. And that's from my own computer hitting docdb directly using the docdb studio. I'd say network performance is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDB is a *service* and not a VM that you control. You cannot choose an affinity group. You can only choose the region in which your database instance will be instantiated.